# Executing C algorithms with exec() will speed up PHP in those places where server response takes too long?

Tags: php, c, performance

My idea is writing C files and executing them with exec() to speed up PHP. Im not sure this is a good practice though. I took special atention to vulnerabilities, so that's not an issue.

This will be applied in big array/object loops and ordering.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it as long as the security issues are addressed.

Comment: Why bother with the php at all - just write the whole "script" in C?

Comment: Does the server have a C compiler?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your comment. I did.

Comment: @WeatherVane I forgot to mention, files are already compiled, .

Comment: So you already know that the executable will run on the server? That was my point. And will the server's anti-virus let you?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I know, right? But I've been told that's not an option, because in my team, only myself and other guy knows C.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, it does. Just need to try the whole implementation, but works fine in both local and remote.

Comment: PHP 7 (not PHP 5.6) is very well optimalized (maybe best of all scripting languages) and is about 6 times slower then assembly (5.6 is about 60 times slower), so i can't imagine how big your arrays/objects are to make it worth it to make assembly ? btw extension for php is better then standalone application

Comment: @Kazz Yes, when i made the initial research, i saw PHP7 is x6 times faster than PHP5.6.x. But it's an old system, and right now we can't change the PHP version. Deliver time is almost here. Thanks for your comment